# Location of the generated header "MyProject-Swift.h"

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, llvm-clang

I am working on a project with mixed Objective-C and Swift; I followed the 
"Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" guide by Apple and it works great.

Out of curiosity, I would like to locate and read the generated header described in the "Mix and Match" chapter :

[image: Objective-C and Swift Mix and Match]

But I can not find it anywhere in Xcode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Finding the editing file

If you want to find the header file in your project, press..

```
cmd + shift + 0
```

when the search bar pops up, search for your file name

```
MyProject-swift.h
```

on the file press

```
cmd + shift + j
```

then right click and tap reveal in finder

### Finding the generated file

1) Go to any objective c class where you import Myproject-swift.h

2) Then press cmd on **"#import Myproject-swift.h"** on top of the file

3) Click "jump to definition"

3) And there it is!

Let me know if that solves your problem!

Answer (score 7):

Using Finder, after a successful build in Xcode 10, the generated header can be found deep in the derived data :

`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
  ProductModuleName-foo/
    Build/
      Intermediates.noindex/
        ProductModuleName.build/
          Debug-iphoneos/
            ProductModuleName.build/
              DerivedSources/
                ProductModuleName-Swift.h`

Where `ProductModuleName` is the `PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME` of your target and `foo` a seemingly random string.